# Why does Process.getrlimit fail for a process opened with IO.popen, but getrlimit(2) in C works?

Tags: ruby, unix

When I spawn a process in ruby and try to get it's resource limits, it fails:

```
io = IO.popen("/usr/bin/cat")
puts Process.getrlimit(io.pid)
```

this throws

```
-:2:in `getrlimit': Invalid argument - getrlimit (Errno::EINVAL)
```

It works for `Process.getrlimit(1)`, returning `[18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551615]`.

When I attempt the same `getrlimit(2)` system call in C, it works!

I modified the Ruby to output the pid and stay running:

```
io = IO.popen("/usr/bin/cat")
puts io.pid
while 1; end
```

Then ran it in the background with `ruby cat.rb &`, used `ps` to get it's pid, I cat get the resource limits using the syscall in C:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int pid = 8657; # from the cat.rb program output
  struct rlimit rlim;
  getrlimit(pid, &rlim);
  printf("Soft limit: %d, ", rlim.rlim_cur);
  printf("Hard limit: %d\n", rlim.rlim_max);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this works, why doesn't ruby let me do the `getrlimit(2)` system call in the same way?

Comment: I am 100 % positive the argument to Process.getrlimit there is **not a pid**

Comment: Not a pid as in not an integer, or not a pid as in, some other value, like the thread ID?

`IO.popen("/usr/bin/cat").pid #=> 15685`

Comment: `EINVAL` is returned when the **2nd** argument to C system call is invalid. If the pid was wrong `ESRCH` would be returned instead. I am not a Ruby programmer and the documentation is **bad** hence I cannot really comment what exactly is the *right way* to do it.

Comment: I see this: `15685 pts/3    00:00:00 cat <defunct>`, is that the problem?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yeah, the ruby docs are really bad here, they told me to go to the manpages for that syscall

Comment: Hem sorry, I was totally confused too. Now writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to C system call `getrlimit` is **not** a pid. It is instead an integer specifying the **resource**, for example `RLIMIT_CPU` or `RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE`. If you put in any random pid as the first argument, then the C system call **will likely fail alike**, returning `-1` and setting `errno` to `EINVAL`. The `getrlimit` always returns the values for **the current process only**.

To get the limits of an arbitrary process on Linux you need to use the **non-portable** `prlimit` system call. That call seems not be supported by plain Ruby, and it cannot be done on Unix systems.

Comment: I just realized this while reading the man page, thank you for your answer